# Get the selected entry from Ext.tree.Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to delete the selected entry on Ext.tree.Panel by clicking on the button from Ext.form.Panel.
I listen to the button click on the controller and call the delete function:

```
...
deleteTreeNode: function (button) {   
        //get tree
        var treepanel = Ext.widget('storagetree');       
        // get selected item
        var selectedNode=treepanel.getSelectionModel().getSelection();     
        console.log(selectedNode);        
        // deleted
        if(selectedNode)
        {
            selectedNode.remove(true);
        }       
    }
....
```

The selectedNode contains an empty array `Array []`

My Ext.tree.Panel:

```
Ext.define('BookApp.view.StorageTree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.storagetree',
    xtype: 'storagetreetype',
    alias: 'widget.storagetree',
    rootVisible: false,  
    store: 'StorageStore',
    itemId: 'StorageTree' 

});
```

How to get the selected record correctly to delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs: [Ext.widget](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.html#method-widget) `Convenient shorthand to create a widget by its xtype or a config object.`
Ext.widget creates another tree and returns the instance, so in the newly created tree there are no selections.
Instead use [reference](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tree.Panel.html#cfg-reference) or [id](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tree.Panel.html#cfg-id)

Here's the example in case of using `id`: [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2m5j)

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me.